# Proof that the axial current is conserved in classical QED

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, field-theory, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory

I am trying to use the Lagrangian of QED (without kinetic terms for photons) to prove that the axial current of QED satisfies $\partial_\mu j^\mu_5 = 2im\bar\psi\gamma^5\psi,$ where $j^\mu_5 = \bar\psi\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi.$ Now, I have used the chiral transformation $\psi \to e^{i\alpha(x)\gamma^5}\psi$ and $\bar \psi \to \bar\psi e^{-i\alpha(x)\gamma^5}$. Working through the calculations, I found that the lagrangian changes to $$\mathcal L - i\alpha(x) (\bar\psi\gamma^5(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m -e\gamma^\mu A_\mu)\psi) +\alpha(x)(\partial_\mu\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi).$$ At this point, I cannot figure out how to get rid of the terms involving $A_\mu$ and the partial derivatives. If you can provide any help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformations are not what you have. The field $\bar \psi$ is defined by  $\bar \psi = \psi^\dagger \gamma_0$, so they should be
$$
\psi\to e^{i\gamma^5 \alpha}\psi, \quad \bar\psi \to \bar\psi e^{i\gamma^5 \alpha}.
$$
This means that $m\bar\psi \psi$ is *not* invariant under the axial transformation

Comment: That would seem to make sense, thanks for the clarification.